# How do I see mongoengine built query?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

How can I print the mongodb query I buid with mongoengine? Example:

```
queryset = Document.objects(**query)
print queryset.to_mongodb_query()
```

Comment: did you want to get `query` which you are passing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. There is a `.query` accessor on the QuerySet. For example:

```
queryset = Document.objects(field__lte=5)
print queryset._query
```

Would produce:

```
{ "field": { "$lte": 5 } }
```

You can also call `.explain()` for descriptive output to the query execution statistics if you wanted that at another log level.